# Yii2 strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: yii2

I am getting this error and i have reread my codes many times. What is the problem?

```
$query->select(['User.name', 'Student.student_ID', 'Student.group_ID'])
            ->from('User')
            ->innerJoin('Student', '`Student`.`user_ID` = `User`.`user_ID`')
            ->leftJoin('Group', '`Group`.`group_ID` = `Student`.`group_ID`')
            ->where(['Student.batch_ID' => $batchid, 'Student.group_ID' =>null, ['!=', 'Student.user_ID', Yii::$app->user->identity->user_ID]])
            ->orWhere(['Student.batch_ID' => $batchid, ['!=', 'Student.group_ID', null], ['!=', 'Student.user_ID', Yii::$app->user->identity->user_ID], ['!=', 'Group.approval_ID', 2]])
            ->orderBy(['User.name' => SORT_ASC]);

$studentarray = $query->all(); <- strtoupper() invoked here?
```

Error messages

[StackTrace1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttb5g.png)

[StackTrace2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4pOX.png)

Conditions I'm going for

Student.batch_ID == $batchID

AND

Student.user_ID != Yii::$app->user->identity->user_ID

AND

Student.group_ID == null OR (if Student.group_ID != null then check group approval_ID == 2)

Comment: show the code where you invoke the strtoupper() too please. not only the select ...

Comment: Hi. Thx for the reply. I've edited my codes. Not sure if that is what you want. @scaisEdge

Comment: I don't see the strupper. function. Please  show the code where you use this function.

Comment: erm. sorry. I didnt use strtoupper(). Strtoupper() is called by some Yii2 function when i use $studentarray = $query->all();

Comment: Where are you using the $studentarray? In GridView?

Comment: Ah. This code is in the controller. $studentarray will be passed to view to be printed in a table. @jeesus

Comment: show all the error trace you get ... i can't find relatiion form your questione and the code and comment you posted..

Comment: @scaisEdge Hi. I've inserted pictures of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$query->select(['User.name', 'Student.student_ID', 'Student.group_ID'])
        ->from('User')
        ->innerJoin('Student', '`Student`.`user_ID` = `User`.`user_ID`')
        ->leftJoin('Group', '`Group`.`group_ID` = `Student`.`group_ID`')
        ->where(['Student.batch_ID' => $batchid])
        ->andWhere(['!=', 'Student.user_ID', Yii::$app->user->identity->user_ID])
        ->andWhere(['Student.group_ID' => null])
        ->orWhere(['==', 'Group.approval_ID', 2]])
        ->orderBy(['User.name' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Take a look at the proper `where()` syntax at [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where%28%29-detail). Haven't tested it out, but this should be the right format for the query.

Comment: HI. I have read the documentation that is how I came up with the codes posted above. The error is now gone but then there is nothing in my $studentarray. Let me try posting up my required conditions and can you check if your codes can satisfy those conditions. Thank you